# Is it possible to change sails.js blueprint-generated camel case controller route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, sails.js

I'm testing out Sails.js and trying to connect to Ember.js on the frontend, but am running into problems with automatically generated controller method routes in Sails.

I have a `TestModel` model generated in Sails.js and I can query the model via `http://localhost:1337/testModel`, or even better for connectivity with Ember, I can set the `pluralize` blueprint config option to true to have that be `http://localhost:1337/testModels`.

However, Ember's naming convention produces requests like `http://localhost:1337/test-models` for the data store query methods.

Is there any way to automatize Sails.js to generate spinal-case instead of camelCase? Or if not, is it possible to have Ember do it?

I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't include writing custom config for every problematic model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remedy this really easy in Ember data by querying for `testModels` instead of `test-models`

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('testColor');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/164/edit

Comment: I am, my model hook function looks like this:
`return this.store.find('testModel')`
but when I inspect the page in browser console, i see an AJAX request being made to /test-models. I assumed Ember automatically transforms 'testModel' into 'test-model'.

Comment: I should probably note that I use `DS.RESTAdapter`.

Comment: The example I put above is using DS.RESTAdapter as well.  Are you customizing the adapter at all?

Comment: No, however I am using the Ember App Kit, perhaps something's happening there by default. I just played around with your jsbin example and removed the mockajax call - the result is good, a request gets fired to 'testModels', not 'test-models'. I'll try replacing EAK with Ember's Starter Kit and see if I can spot the difference... Anyway, your answer pointed me in the right direction, so I'm marking as accepted. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In sails v0.10 you can specify a custom API resource identity by overriding the `identity` property on both the model and the controller.

```
// FooResourceController.js
module.exports = {
  identity: 'foo_resource'
}

// FooResource.js
module.exports = {
  identity: 'foo_resource',
  attributes: {

  }
}

// Routes bound on lift
//
// get    /foo_resource
// post   /foo_resource
// put    /foo_resource
// delete /foo_resource
```